# Select build type at conan build step

Tags: c, build, cross-platform, cross-compiling, conan

This is a simple need of selecting build type when calling conan build.

Normally we have to call `conan install` with the desired build type and then `conan build` with the following commands :

```
conan install conanfile.py install -s build_type=Debug
conan build conanfile.py
```

I have seen that we can force conan to do an install with the build command using `--intall`. I have tried the following command but it does not update the `settings.build_type` value.

```
conan build conanfile.py --install -s build_type=Release
```

Does any one have an idea how to change the build type with `conan build` command or at least pass a variables to be checked later in the `conanfile.py`

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

The `conan build` command will use whatever configuration was provided to the `conan install` command. So the way to change configuration (settings, options, etc) is to do a `conan install` with the right configuration.

When a `conan install` command is executed it will create information about dependencies for the current configuration (profile, settings, options), and will generate files as *conanbuildinfo.cmake* as defined by the Conan generators. The `conan build` command will use those files to find the right dependencies binaries for that configuration. Trying to `conan build` with a different configuration without updating the dependencies generated files will typically result in compile or link errors for using the incorrect dependencies binaries.

Comment: Keeping in mind the `cmake_layout()`, which creates `build/Release` and `build/Debug` folders: If we call `conan install` twice, for example first calling `conan install` with a debug profile and then with a release profile, we could have two conanbuildinfo.cmake generated. Wouldn't it then be possible to build for the specified `build_type` using `conan build`? Currently, calling `conan build .` will still use the build_type that was set during the latest call to conan install, regardless of what is passed to `conan build`.

Comment: ``cmake_layout()`` is a modern feature, that should go together with the new build system integrations, like ``CMakeDeps`` and ``CMakeToolchain`` generators, but it will not work with the legacy ``cmake`` generator (the one generating ``conanbuildinfo.cmake``)

Comment: Sorry I forgot to mention that we use already the new `CMakeDeps` and `CMakeToolchain` generators but `conan build .` will still build the configuration that was last used during `conan install`. Does conan take this information from `conanbuildinfo.txt`? And will it be possible to set the `build_type` during `conan build . -s build_type=Release/Debug` or is this feature not planned/possible? Thanks

Comment: Then, better create a new issue (typically better in Github), because this one is unrelated, it is talking about a different generator. Conan 2.0 indeed will take settings as parameter to ``conan build``, but not yet in 1.X

Comment: Thanks drodri, is this also somewhere documented in the documentation that conan 1.X doesn't yet consider the settings as parameter to `conan build`?

Comment: Well, it doesn't document the absences of parameters that exist in future versions, indeed, but the docs of ``conan build`` should show that this argument doesn't exist.